# Running multiple spring batch jobs from one single application

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement where i need to run multiple jobs from one single application. The requirement is to make it configurable , all properties of batch application should come from application.properties and upon running my application should pick all the properties and run accordingly.

I have two xml files which contain jobs, the entire structure of the two xml files are same , only the ids are different. These xml files refer their properties from application properties defined separately for each of them.

I am able to start the jobs successfully and both jobs run as per the logs. But the issue is the properties they refer from their respective application.properties files seems to be overriding each other as a result it picks up only one of the properties.

I tried scoping the bean which refers my properties with job=scope but it throws an error
Cannot convert value of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29 implementing org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject

Can you guide me how to start with this ?

Comment: Did you consider googling and check about `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` before posting this SO please?